# Where am I going wrong with openCL and the "Failed to set kernel argument" failure?

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been trying following a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8jnAuFMnPY) to create a simple hello world program utilising opencl. It was building fine until I have to call the kernel then it says the following...

> "2017-10-14 11:43:33.049472+0100 openclTest3[1052:70809] [CL_INVALID_KERNEL] : OpenCL Error : Failed to set kernel argument! Kernel given is invalid!"

Where am I going wrong? I have been over the tutorial code several times. Used someone else's code from the same tutorial, and looked at all the similar questions on here that i could find. As far as I can see there is no difference in the code.

I am using a late 2013 mbp with Intel Iris Pro graphics. I have linked the opencl framework in Xcode.

I have 3 files main.cpp, helloWorld.cl, and the opencl.cpp file which I won't post for obvious reasons.

main.cpp

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "cl.hpp"

int main() {
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;

    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);  //the os?

    auto platform = platforms.front(); //gets the first element of the platforms array

    std::vector<cl::Device> devices; //??
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices); //gets the gpu devices installed in the system //& creates a pointer.

    auto device = devices[0]; //gets the first element in the devices array

    std::ifstream helloWorldFile("helloWorld.cl");
    std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(helloWorldFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources sources(1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length() + 1));
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    auto err = program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");

    char buf[16];

    cl::Buffer memBuf(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(buf));

    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "HelloWorld");
    kernel.setArg(0,  memBuf);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
    queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(memBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf);

    std::cout << buf;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

helloWorld.cl

```
kernel void HelloWorld(global char* data){
    data[0 ] = 'H' ;
    data[1 ] = 'E' ;
    data[2 ] = 'L' ;
    data[3 ] = 'L' ;
    data[4 ] = 'O' ;
    data[5 ] = '-' ;
    data[6 ] = 'W' ;
    data[7 ] = 'O' ;
    data[8 ] = 'R' ;
    data[9 ] = 'L' ;
    data[10] = 'D' ;
    data[11] = '!' ;
    data[12] = '\n';
    data[13] = 0   ;
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the program.build() call?

Comment: i've tried with and without it and i still get the same results as before. 
i forgot to uncomment it. i have edited now :p

Comment: Most likely one of the OpenCL API calls fails for your program. Try adding a #define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS before #include "cl.hpp". This would throw an exception if something fails.

Comment: sweet, i added that and it has thrown following error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cl::Error: clBuildProgram

Comment: assuming you wrote in the original code __kernel and __global, your code should be compiling correctly.

Comment: yeah i only changed that out of hope. i've compiled with underscores. and linked the opencl framework in xcode. i think it's just a lost cause. do you know of any other frameworks, like open framework or thrust, that allow opencl programming at a higher level that aren't specific to CUDA??

Answer (score 0):

I know its already been years but my guess is that its cause u have the `memBuf`'s flag set as `CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_READ_ONLY`.

I think what you'd probably wanna use is `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`.